# How to implement Bootstrap in WordPress Plugin Boilerplate correct? https://wppb.me/

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, boilerplate

I want to know how to integrate Bootstrap the correct way into this Boilerplate.

Here some Code from the public/Class-public.php

```
/**
 * Register the JavaScript for the public-facing side of the site.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function enqueue_scripts() {

    /**
     * This function is provided for demonstration purposes only.
     *
     * An instance of this class should be passed to the run() function
     * defined in Price_Hubble_Loader as all of the hooks are defined
     * in that particular class.
     *
     * The Price_Hubble_Loader will then create the relationship
     * between the defined hooks and the functions defined in this
     * class.
     */

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/pricepublic.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the same [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function and add first params as a handler and second param as a path in here I am using CDN path as an example.

```
public function enqueue_scripts() {

    /**
     * This function is provided for demonstration purposes only.
     *
     * An instance of this class should be passed to the run() function
     * defined in Test_Loader as all of the hooks are defined
     * in that particular class.
     *
     * The Test_Loader will then create the relationship
     * between the defined hooks and the functions defined in this
     * class.
     */

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/test-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.5.2', false );

}
```